# D3.js: Accessing the element's previous datum inside of .attrTween()

Tags: d3.js, svg

Is there a way to access an element's previous data inside of its `attrTween` tween function?

I want to update my donut chart's arcs using previous values of `startAngle`/`endAngle`, but it seems that the only way to access those angles is to cache them before applying a new data set. I know there is 3rd parameter in the tween function which is current value of the attribute, but in my case it's a raw string value of the SVG path's `d` attribute, something like `M53.86870,HURR-DURR...`. I'd like to use angles, calculated by `pie` layout and not to deal with the raw string.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j0nj2h22/)

Comment: You need to save any values you want access to explicitly, just like it's done in the pie chart tween examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the hack that you can do if you already have a lot of code written and you don't want to rewrite your pie logic. It involves catching though. This solution introduces a wrapper around `data` method that stores previous value of the bound element on the element every time you call `data` with the new data set. It wasn't tested, so use it at your own risk if you have to.

```
var origData = d3.selection.prototype.data;

d3.selection.prototype.data = function() {
    this.each(function(){
        this.__pdata__ = this.__data__;
    });
    return origData.apply(this, arguments);
};

d3.selectAll('div')
    .data([0,1,2,3])
    .each(function(d){
        console.log(this.__pdata__, d);
    });

d3.selectAll('div')
        .data([0,1,2,3].reverse())
        .each(function(d){
            console.log(this.__pdata__, d);
        });
```

Comment: Nah, I don't mind rewriting my code. In fact, I'm OK with my approach in the JSFiddle, just wondering if there is a better way to extract previous values without using an additional variable to store previous dataset. But I got your point, will accept that as the right answer. Thanks.

Comment: Yep, unfortunately d3 doesn't store previous datum of the element by default yet, but it can be augmented if needed.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's worth mentioning [`d3.local`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#local-variables). The solution is essentially the same as your own solution but the data is stored against the DOM nodes (like @sergeyz solution) and `prev_data` becomes a reference to access that data.

```js
// prev_data provides a getter and setter
var prev_data = d3.local();
function update(data) {
  var $paths = g.selectAll('path');
  // Before we update the data, update the prev_data
  $paths.each(function(d) { prev_data.set(this, d) });
  var join = $paths.data(data);
  join.transition().attrTween('d', function (d) {
    // We can now get the individual datum for this node
    var p = prev_data.get(this, d);
    ...
  }
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x0zbvtk6/21/)

@sergeyz solution is neat, but monkey-patching D3 and reaching into its internals (`__data__`) may not be something everyone is comfortable with. Also, `prev_data` can be used across many components.